# Converting a list of dicts from unicode

Tags: python, flask-restful

I have this data that I am sending as JSON to a Flask RESTful API as the payload:

```
{"Order": [
            {
                "Menu_Id":1, 
                "Menu_Price":10,
                "Order_ItemQty":2
            },

            {
                "Menu_Id":2,
                "Menu_Price":18,
                "Order_ItemQty":3
            }
        ],

        "User_Id":user_id
    }
```

I would then like to work with it in python as a normal list of dicts. I am fetching it using reqparse as below:

```
UserOrdersparser.add_argument('Order', action='append', required=True, 
                              help='This field cant be left blank!')
UserOrdersparser.add_argument('User_Id', type=int, required=True, help='This 
                              field cant be left blank!')
```

Then trying to access the 'order' list dict values:

```
json_payload = UserOrders.parser.parse_args()
json_payload['Order'][0]['Menu_Id']
```

But I keep getting the below error:

```
>       print(json_payload['Order'][0]['Menu_Id'])
E       TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The print out of the 'orders' list is as below and I think the 'u's are the cause, but I have tried decoding them using the encode() method with no success:

```
print(json_payload)['Orders']

# 'Order': [u"{u'Menu_Id': 1, u'Menu_Price': 10, u'Order_ItemQty': 2}", u"{u'Menu_Id': 2, u'Menu_Price': 18, u'Order_ItemQty': 3}"]
```

Note: Accessing the second item of the JSON data `'User_Id'` has no problem.

How do I get the list back or convert it get a proper python list that looks like:

```
[

            {'Menu_Id': 1, 'Menu_Price': 10, 'Order_ItemQty': 2}, 
            {'Menu_Id': 2, 'Menu_Price': 18, 'Order_ItemQty': 3}

        ]
```

Comment: works fine`import json

j = '{"Order":[{"Menu_Id":1,"Menu_Price":10,"Order_ItemQty":2},{"Menu_Id":2,"Menu_Price":18,"Order_ItemQty":3}],"User_Id":"user_id"}'
js = json.loads(j)
print(js['Order'][0]['Menu_Id']) print(js['Order'])` prints 1, in above json `user_id` should be String/Value/Object

Comment: From your code, there might be issue with `UserOrders.parser.parse_args()`

Comment: You need to show how you've defined the fields for reqparse. It doesn't seem like you've told it that Orders is a resource withits own fields.

Comment: @dkb I'm getting the below error:

`self = <flask.json.JSONDecoder object at 0x034DF170>
s = {'User_Id': 1, 'Order': [u"{u'Menu_Id': 1, u'Menu_Price': 10, u'Order_ItemQty': 2}", u"{u'Menu_Id': 2, u'Menu_Price': 18, u'Order_ItemQty': 3}"
_w = <built-in method match of _sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x026594D0>

    def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
        """ Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` or ``unicode``
        instance containing a JSON document """

>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
E       TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: You can try here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman other than as laid out in the second part of my question above, is there another way to define the args you expect reqparse to collect? Could you kindly demonstrate how to define that the 'Orders' argument has its own fields?

Comment: @dkb Here is where our wires are abit crossed, when I get the JSON data from reqparse, it look like this:

`{'User_Id': 1, 'Order': [u"{u'Menu_Id': 1, u'Menu_Price': 10, u'Order_ItemQty': 2}", u"{u'Menu_Id': 2, u'Menu_Price': 18, u'Order_ItemQty': 3}"]}`

Using json.loads on the above, yields the error I talking about, the unicode characters seem to be the issue and are what I hope to get help getting rid of.

Comment: This is just String form of JSON, and not Json, so you need to get actual json as response and not string.

Comment: @dkb you are right, even though it has the unicode characters I can still parse it as string. I think I am just confusing myself properly parsing the list from reqparse. I resulted to using get_json() instead and works fine. Thanks.